# Unused parameter warning for .NET activity trigger that accepts no parameters

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

```
public async Task<data[]> GetDataAsync([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
        {
            //get data
            return data.ToArray();
        }
```

I have the above function that does not need to accept any params. With this code I have the warning

> Error IDE0060 Remove unused parameter 'context' if it is not part of a shipped public API

However if a remove the parameter like so

```
public async Task<data[]> GetDataAsync([ActivityTrigger]){...}
```

I have 2 errors

> Identifier expected

> Type expected

What is the preferred way to handle this situation?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me - whatever you've used to "remove unused parameter" for some reason did not remove the attribute associated with the parameter...  should be `public async Task<data[]> GetDataAsync(){...}`. But whether you can actually remove the parameter is unclear without the context (but that does not look like a question you asked).

Comment: Then it would just be a regular function no? I tried removing everything and then the function is no longer part of the context it seems

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question to clarify what your goal is - activity trigger without context (unlikely to happen - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions), ignore particular warning (indeed link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0060 and clarify why it was not enough), something else.

Comment: The workarounds are [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0060)

Comment: There are indeed scenarios where an activity function might not need to accept any input, especially when the activity function's behavior is not contingent upon its input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases of False Positives. Starting with C# 9 you can use discard parameters like below

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(SayHello))]
public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext _)
{
    return $"Hello Daredevil!";
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0060